# General phenomenology of quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, interactions

Resume: Unfortunately, the moderators of the forum, like some of the participants, were unable to understand that the question was not about "personal theories", but rather about a widely accepted scientific concept called QFT. It seems to me that this is blatant discrimination.

Some respected forum members, including scientists, [say](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129448/discussion-on-question-by-arman-armenpress-interaction-of-quark-and-gluon-fields) that my views on Quantum Field Theory are outdated and wrong. Well, I will very briefly state my understanding, and if it is wrong, I will ask the forum participants to substantiate what exactly is wrong (preferably with links to the relevant scientific articles). Otherwise, it turns out that my five-year research was completely meaningless. So I need help.

There are many different quantum field theories. The simplest is a QFT without interaction or a free QFT. This free field mode is a toy model, that is, it does not fully correspond to the real physical world (found in experiments), but it is very convenient for calculations in zero approximation.

However, to calculate real values ​​(for example, the scattering amplitude), it is necessary to include the interaction of the fields, since in reality the fields are constantly interacting. In this case, a new theory is obtained - QFT with interaction. This is already much more complicated, and in this case, perturbation theory is often used. Calculations are performed using Feynman diagrams, gradually refining the result.

Question. What exactly is wrong with this view? I would really like to receive a complete and well-founded answer.

**Postscript: Some forum members are demanding that the question be closed, allegedly based on the fact that it is not based on basic physical concepts, or that the question is about personal theory. I dare to assure that this is not true. Every person who even remotely understands QFT knows that the post is talking about generally accepted physical concepts. I hope the moderators will take this fact into account. As for the participants unreasonably demanding the closure of the post. I would ask them to be brave and write more specifically about their objections.**

Comment: *Some respected forum members, including scientists, say that my views on Quantum Field Theory are outdated and wrong.* -  Please include some links / references.

Comment: @Jakob okay https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129448/discussion-on-question-by-arman-armenpress-interaction-of-quark-and-gluon-fields

Comment: *"fields are described as quantum systems in Fock space with occupation numbers"* - you have just thrown around terminology randomly

Comment: @NiharKarve I'm sorry, I don't speak English very well. The crux of the question is in the difference between a free field (toy model) and a field with interaction (a real physical situation).

Comment: Describing free fields is a part of QFT, but this does not make te whole theory - describing interactions (as a minimum via the scattering matrix expansion) is a major part of any QFT textbook.

Comment: @RogerVadim Can we say that the free field is only a zero approximation?

Comment: There is nothing in this post that is intrinsically wrong. Still, no one in the linked chat claims that something in this post is wrong. The say that OP's oldest question is unclear, which is true.

Comment: Yes, like a free particle in vacuum in Newtonian mechanics. If the coupling constants are small, we can add the interactions via perturbative approach built upon the non-interacting solutions - this is done in QED. Otherwise we need non-perturbative/strong coupling approaches - instanton methods, renormalization group, etc.

Comment: @RogerVadim <If the coupling constants are small, we can add the interactions via perturbative approach built upon the non-interacting solutions - this is done in QED>. That is, in Feynman diagrams, particles are considered free between the vertices (which correspond to the interaction)?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress yes. But you have to keep in mind that Feynman diagrams are not a representation of reality, but of mathematical perturbstion series. Also, one often sums infinite subseries of diagrams, which gives non-perturbative results, in principle.

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, this is an attempt to describe the interacting QFT using the terms of the non-interacting theory.

Comment: The QCD vacuum is a nonperturbative active and roiling place: [behold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0Nxu-Mqc-0). [Especially here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZgZI5vymiM).

Comment: @CosmasZachos This can be thought of as a "seething sea" of virtual mesons and virtual gluons providing strong interactions between virtual quark-antiquark pairs. At least that's what my teacher said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post just one certainly important aspect of Quantum field theory is described. One starts up with a linear theory and in order to see real physics coupling between the fields is needed. And as non-linear theories only in the rarest cases can be solved, one applies perturbation theory.

However, Quantum field theory is more than that. There are a whole panoply of non-perturbative effects, like solitons, QCD-vacuum, instantons, or topological Quantum field theory and many others even I am not aware of. So the description in the post is not wrong, but incomplete. Certainly non-perturbative effects are part of more advanced Quantum field theory. I invite the author of the post to study them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is more about whether quantum fields interact or not. As far as I know, quantum fields interact constantly, but the nonperturbative description of such fields (especially in the case of a strong coupling) is a rather difficult task. If the coupling constant is small, the description can be perturbative: starting with free field theory and gradually adding perturbation theory terms with interactions.